# Как правильно оганизовать взаимодействие с server API применительно к архитектуре VIPER?

Tags: ios, swift

Всем доброго времени суток! 
Пишу приложение на Swift, в котором будет очень много запросов к серверу через API. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно разместить и организовать все это применительно к архитектуре VIPER. Более конкретно: По идее interactor обращается к сервису с запросом на некие данные? Как правильно организовать этот класс сервиса? Синглтон или просто набор методов? Нужно ли писать протокол для этого сервиса, как для других элементов модуля VIPER? Какие есть bad/good practices по работе с серврным API в Swift через Alamofire(да по идее без разницы, хоть нативом)?